# How to display only parent label when select an item in multicascader rsuite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, rsuite

```
  { label: 'Create', value: 'create' },
  { label: 'Read', value: 'read' },
  { label: 'Write', value: 'write' },
  { label: 'Delete', value: 'delete' },
  { label: 'Approve', value: 'approve' }
];

const multiCascaderData = data.map(item => {
  const children = permissions.map(permission => ({
    label: permission.label,
    value: `${item.id}-${permission.value}`
  }));

  return {
    label: item.description,
    value: item.id,
    children: children
  };
});
return (
  <MultiCascader
    data={multiCascaderData}
    labelKey="label"
    valueKey="value"
    childrenKey="children"
  />
);
```

I have a data which it has a `label` and `value`

`[{label: 'room1', value: 'room1'},{label: 'room2', value: 'room2'}]`

then I added the permission. what I'm trying to do is when I try to select an item in child it should return the parent label where it should be like this.

[image]